# Creating a new column based on two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, paste

I have a reproducible `df` where there are repeat samplings from an individual. For each sample I track the Order that the samples were taken and the Media used (A or B).

```
dat <- data.frame(IndID = factor(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)),
          Order = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2),
          Media = factor(c("A", "B", "B","A","B","A", "A")))
dat
  IndID Order Media
1     1     1     A
2     1     2     B
3     2     1     B
4     2     2     A
5     2     3     B
6     3     1     A
7     3     2     A
```

I want to make a new column that contains the Media and a number that signifies the sampling Order within each level of Media. Said differently, grouping by IndID and Media, I want to make a new column that orders the samples. For each individual, if there are only two samples in two different Media (like IndID 1), the new value would be "A1" and "B1". If there are two samples from the same Media, the new values need to be "B1" and "B2" in an order that follows the sampling Order.

Given the above data, I am trying to create the following column

```
dat$WantThis <- c("A1", "B1","B1", "A1","B2", "A1", "A2")

  IndID Order Media WantThis
1     1     1     A       A1
2     1     2     B       B1
3     2     1     B       B1
4     2     2     A       A1
5     2     3     B       B2
6     3     1     A       A1
7     3     2     A       A2
```

I have been trying to use the `dplyr` package but cannot connect the dots on what should be included as the 2nd argument to `paste`.

```
dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat %>% group_by(IndID, Media) %>% mutate(MediaOrder = paste0(Media, ???? )))
```

Thanks in advance. I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(IndID, Media) %>% mutate(WantThis = paste0(Media, row_number()))` probably

Comment: `dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(IndID, Media) %>% mutate(WantThis = paste0(Media, row_number()))` generates `Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Which `dplyr` version you have? It works fine foe me. You could try `mutate(WantThis = paste0(Media, 1:n()))` instead maybe

Comment: I updated `dplyr` and it works fine.  Thanks.  Post as answer?

Comment: It was already posted by some dude. And it's a dupe anyway, so can't post anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the row number of the grouping it should get you what you want.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(IndID = factor(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)),
                  Order = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2),
                  Media = factor(c("A", "B", "B","A","B","A", "A")))

res <- dat %>%
  group_by(IndID, Media) %>%
  mutate(count = row_number(),
         WantThis = paste(Media,count,sep=""))

#Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
#Groups: IndID, Media [5]
#
#   IndID Order  Media count WantThis
#  (fctr) (dbl) (fctr) (int)    (chr)
#1      1     1      A     1       A1
#2      1     2      B     1       B1
#3      2     1      B     1       B1
#4      2     2      A     1       A1
#5      2     3      B     2       B2
#6      3     1      A     1       A1
#7      3     2      A     2       A2
```